# Getting image from path & crop the Image

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

Its open the "choose from galary" option but i dont want this. I want directly showing the croping option on image. I have used intent for that

```
// Crop.java
private String defaultImagePath;
final int PIC_CROP = 1;
private Uri mCropImagedUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.crop);
    cropImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    seekBarCrop = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarCrop);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String imagePath = b.getString("imagePath");
    defaultImagePath = imagePath;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    cropImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    cropImageActivity(defaultImagePath, cropImage);
}


private void cropImageActivity(String path, View cropImage) {

        try {
            mCropImagedUri = Uri.parse(path);
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(mCropImagedUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();           
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        if (data != null) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            cropImage.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```